# Why is my UIWebView showing up as "[0]" in my variable view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a MasterDetail application.

In my DetailViewController I have a UIWebView synthesized as _myWebView:
[image]

On my `MasterViewController` I have various `UIViewControllers` that I `push` and `pop` and each of them contain options that allow me to display something in this `UIWebView`.

I recently added a new `ViewController` on the master side but whenever I try to display something on the `UIWebView` from this new `ViewController` (which is done by passing data to the `DetailViewController`) my `_myWebView` property show up as **[0]** in my variable view (or watch window).

It doesn't even show the variable's name.

[image]

The `UIWebView` also doesn't display anything as requested.

It's probably something stupid but I'm not seeing it.
So first of I need to know where this [0] comes from, maybe that's a hint as to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: how about clean and quit xcode and a re-run.

Comment: Clean didn't work, but XCode quit + reset simulator did the trick. Lost count by now on how many hours I've wasted on problems that are solved by restarting XCode. Thanks